# Replacing multiple substrings from a string in Java/Android

Tags: java, android

Example:

```
String originalString = "This is just a string folks";
```

I want to remove(or replace them with "") : `1. "This is" , 2. "folks"`
Desired output :

```
finalString = "just a string";
```

For a sole substring it's easy, we can just use replace/replaceAll. 
I also know it works for various numeric values `replace("[0-9]","")`
But can that be done for characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a function like below:

```
String replaceMultiple (String baseString, String ... replaceParts) {
    for (String s : replaceParts) {
        baseString = baseString.replaceAll(s, "");
    }
    return baseString;
}
```

And call it like:

```
String finalString = replaceMultiple("This is just a string folks", "This is", "folks");
```

You can pass multiple strings that are to be replaced after the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think there is a solution via 'Pattern's, perhaps, for this task?

Comment: Since your pattern is a bit vague, possibly not. You could pass through regex to do this, however you need to be careful with your pattern matching

Comment: Thanks. 
last question, if I have the word "notbe" for example. and I want to remove all the "not" prefix , so that "notbe" would become "be". Do you have an idea how can that be achieved?

Comment: The above function would do that task for you.

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```
String originalString = "This is just a string folks";
originalString = originalString.replace("This is", "");
originalString = originalString.replace("folks", "");
//originalString is now finalString
```

Comment: Well that solution is pretty obvious. My question Is whether there is a more efficient or more "elegant" way to do so?
Cause I have many substrings to cover, and I want to be able to easily add more in the future.

Comment: ah sorry... Yeah sure... but I don't know how it would work in your case. Use replaceAll("[A-Za-z]", "")

Comment: you can always create an enum of all the substrings you want to replace and can easily add more in case you need to scale up in future.